# Azure App Service has exception during snapshot upload and stops working correctly

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a Problem where a App Service is temporary unavailable. But its a bit special...
The App is running but one task of the app is to send e mails via a Mail Provider - Mailgun. And from time to time it isn't sending mails. We have checked the mailgun and there is no problem and when I restart this App Service all mails are sent.
So I search a lot and find a log from the snapshot uploader in the app service where an exception occurs approximately at the same time when the mail service is not working.

The Exception is the following:

```
SnapshotUploader.exe Error: 0 : Exception during dump processing: 

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<PutBlockImpl>b__5c(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StorageAsyncResult`1.End()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobWriteStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.WriteDeflaterOutput(Boolean isAsync)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.InternalWrite(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Boolean isAsync)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobWriteStream.Flush()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobWriteStream.Commit()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobWriteStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.Uploader.Uploader.<UploadFileToBlobCompressed>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.Uploader.Uploader.<UploadBlobWithRetriesAsync>d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.Uploader.Uploader.<UploadMinidumpAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.Uploader.Uploader.<ProcessOneDumpFileAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.Uploader.Uploader.<RunMainLoopAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
Request Information
RequestID:da887501-801e-006f-3c95-121388000000
RequestDate:Wed, 26 Jan 2022 09:19:38 GMT
StatusMessage:Ingress is over the account limit.
ErrorCode:ServerBusy
ErrorMessage:Ingress is over the account limit.
RequestId:da887501-801e-006f-3c95-121388000000
Time:2022-01-26T09:19:38.4648110Z
```

Is it possible that this exception blocks the app service or something so it cant work correctly? And how can I fix this Exception?

Comment: To resolve `ErrorMessage:Ingress is over the account limit.`, you can refer to [Blob storage max storage capacity VS ingress limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/26886/blob-storage-max-storage-capacity-vs-ingress-limit.html) and [Scalability and performance targets for standard storage accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account)

Comment: Actualy no solution for this. I have contacted the azure support for the incress limit. Because it is set to the standard value and this app has nothing special in it. So normaly it shouldn't break the limit.